# Optimizing N2 CMS

Tags: c#, .net, content-management-system, n2

N2 CMS is extremely slow to start up. From what I've heard, on the first JIT compile it loads all of itself into memory which takes 2 to 3 minutes on a fast system, but can take upwards to 10 on my local machine.

This, of course, makes debugging extremely, extremely painful.

Anyone know of anyway to optimize this? I've tried searching through the N2 documentation, but it's really bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

n2 can be quite chatty, especially when loading children and checking permissions.  There are optimisations you can make though, [This page might be of some help](http://n2cms.com/wiki/Performance.aspx).

Regarding startup specifically, the first tip on that page might be of some help.

Comment: Just tried this out. I've gone from 8 minute first page loads to 15 secs. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but as far as I'm aware N2 CMS is asp.net based, therefore you have a number of [compilation options available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/399f057w(VS.85).aspx) to you, including [pre-compiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227976(VS.85).aspx), which should help with start-up times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to network latency. Debugging locally with a remote database was extremely slow, however copying over the database to my local instance of SQL Server speeds things up considerably.

This issue is most likely caused by the massive amount of content we have our in our CMS database. Not sure if it's a problem with how NHibernate is being used by N2 or how NHibernate works internally.